# Help with donut tutorial

Tags: modeling

I've been following the Blender guru donut tutorial for 3.0 and I'm having trouble with the icing. Even when I hide the solidify modifier on the icing, I'm getting a lot of weird clipping with the donut, and I can't seem to get the (magnet?) snapping to work right. When I try to extrude the icing down it clips through the donut, and trying to grab a vertex I'm also having clipping issues. I'm sure I've done something stupid but thought I would ask here before I restart without knowing what I did wrong. Here are some images of the problem, I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

[images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWmqO.jpg)

Comment: Just type "donut icing" into the search field at the top of this page and press Return...

Comment: please don't add external links to pics here. Just paste them in the question. Thanks.

Comment: If the icing is low poly, so its faces may penetrate the faces underneath, one thing you could do, if moving vertices doesn't work, is subdivide the icing

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that ive spotted that might help - your on the Blender version 2.9.
As you stated, that tutorial is for 3.0
I would suggest updating to 3.0 before continueing the tutorial.